# Linked list insertion not working for 0th index

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, insertion

I have wrote a c program for linked list, and a function to insert a node at an index.
When calling the function for index 0, The head pointer doesn't seem to be updating in the main function even though i have updated it in the insertion function.
The traverse function doesn't seem to be printing the newly added element.
Please help.

Code:

[Node struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EvZk.png)
[Main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ0Bi.png)
[Function for traversing and printing the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwBIf.png)
[Insertion function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgkRA.png)

## Output:

[After insertion output is still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuMxP.png)

Comment: In order to put potential answerers into a more helpful mood: a) tone down your formatting b) show code as formatted text instead of picture of text c) provide a [mre] d) search for other questions and answers about your problem, assuming that it is the usual lack of double pointer or return of changed head pointer there are many

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I provided a duplicate with an answer demonstrating even both methods at once.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, its my first time on the platform.

Answer (score -1):

This is because when you insert at the beginning, you have to change the head pointer to point to the newly inserted element. For that to work, the *insert_to_index* function has to tell its caller (*main* function) what the new head is. Changing ythe value of the function parameter `head` inside *insert_to_index* is not enough, because that doesn't change the `head` in *main*.

One way to fix it is returning the new `head` value. To do that, change `return;` to `return head;` in *insert_at_index* (and change its return type from `void` to `struct node*`, and also add `return head;` to the end), and also change its call to `head = insert_at_index(head, 0, 0);` in *main*.

Another, alternative way to fix it is changing the parameter to `struct node **head` (two stars), changing `head` to `*head` within *insert_at_index*, and changing `head` to `&head` when *insert_to_index* is called from *main*.

Comment: Pity you did not trust my comment that a dupe (or several) exists.